# Correct entries in date column based on time column for a timeseries dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a timeseries dataframe that has three columns... date, time and value and it looks like this:

```
**date**              **time**            **value**
11.03.2020            1103                   5  
11.03.2020            0000                   10
11.03.2020            0100                   6
12.03.2020            0201                   8
12.03.2020            0305                   7
12.03.2020            0400                   4
```

basically the time column is incrementing by 60 (+-5) mins for every row. I want to correct my date column values in such a way that whenever the time is 0000 (+-5) the day part of the date column increments by 1 untill the next 0000 (+-5) time value is encountered and than it increments by 1 again untill the next such time value is encountered or the end of the data frame is reached.

The result should look like this:

```
**date**              **time**            **value**
11.03.2020            1103                   5  
12.03.2020            0000                   10
12.03.2020            0100                   6
12.03.2020            0201                   8
12.03.2020            0305                   7
12.03.2020            0400                   4
```

I would appreciate some help. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parse the strings in column `date` as `datetime`

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True)
```

Create a boolean mask `m` by comparing the `time` column with `0000`, using boolean indexing add the `DateOffset` of `1 days` to the values in date column where the boolean mask holds true, then `mask` and `forward fill` the values in updated date column where the current date is less that previous date

```
m = df['time'].eq('0000')
df.loc[m, 'date'] += pd.DateOffset(days=1)
df['date'] = df['date'].mask(df['date'].diff().dt.days.lt(0)).ffill()
```

---

```
        date  time  value
0 2020-03-11  1103      5
1 2020-03-12  0000     10
2 2020-03-12  0100      6
3 2020-03-12  0201      8
4 2020-03-12  0305      7
5 2020-03-12  0400      4
```

Comment: very nice +1, using `DateOffset(days=1)` automatically handles the end-of-month transitions correctly

Comment: Thanks @tdy that is because `DateOffset` respects calendar arithmetic :)

Comment: Thanks @Shubam, works beautifully. Your solution makes me want to learn more.

Comment: @tdy I liked your solution too and it worked, souldn't have deleted it.