# Calculate values in date column based on time column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
**date**              **time**            **price**
NaN                      1103                   5  
NaN                      0010                   10
NaN                      0100                   6
NaN                      0201                   8
NaN                      0015                   7
12.03.2020               0400                   4
NaN                      0500                   6
NaN                      0800                   3
NaN                      1000                   4
NaN                      1140                   5
12.03.2020               1200                   2
NaN                      0030                   1
NaN                      0112                   0
```

I want to fill the NaN values in the date column by calculating the date through the time field. My idea is to locate the first non empty value in the date column. Once I have that  I want to bfill() and ffill() in such a way that dates are changed at a time measurement before and after midnight. So in our example the data will look like this after bfill() from the first non empty cell:

```
     **date**              **time**            **price**
    10.03.2020               1103                   5  
    11.03.2020               0010                   10
    11.03.2020               0100                   6
    11.03.2020               0201                   8
    12.03.2020               0015                   7
    12.03.2020               0400                   4
    NaN                      0500                   6
    NaN                      0800                   3
    NaN                      1000                   4
    NaN                      1140                   5
    12.03.2020               1200                   2
    NaN                      0030                   1
    NaN                      0112                   0
```

This is how it will look after ffil() from the first non empty date value:

```
          **date**             **time**            **price**
        10.03.2020               1103                   5  
        11.03.2020               0010                   10
        11.03.2020               0100                   6
        11.03.2020               0201                   8
        12.03.2020               0015                   7
        12.03.2020               0400                   4
        12.03.2020               0500                   6
        12.03.2020               0800                   3
        12.03.2020               1000                   4
        12.03.2020               1140                   5
        12.03.2020               1200                   2
        13.03.2020               0030                   1
        13.03.2020               0112                   0
```

It is worth noting that the first non empty value can appear anywhere in the date column. Would appreciate some help in solving this problem. Thanks

```
date = [NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,"12.03.2020", NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN, "12.03.2020", NaN, NaN}
time = [1103,0010,0100,0201,0015,0400,0500,0800,1000,1140,1200,0030,0112]
price= [5,10,6,8,7,4,6,3,4,5,2,1,0]
```

**Edit**:Lists added

Comment: can you post your data in a list format for easier recreate? also, are you sure the bfill and ffill are consistent and no conflict or ambiguity between 2 days?

Comment: I've added the lists, however I wasn't sure how to input NaN's.
Yes bfill() and ffill() are consistent, day changes only after midnight.

Comment: How can we know the time(s) related to 12.03.2020 are AM or PM? And if they are AM why we have to move to 13.03 in next row? These do not seem to be well defined

Comment: The time follows the 24 hour format. So 12:00 am (midnight) to 12:00 pm is 0000 - 1200 in the 24 hour format.

Answer (score 4):

Iterating on [Shubham's `DateOffset` idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67330070/13138364), here is a version that computes offsets relative to some known date and applies the offsets as [**`Timedelta`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html):

```py
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date, dayfirst=True)
df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time, format='%H%M').dt.time
offset = df.time.shift().bfill().gt(df.time).cumsum()

known = df.date.notnull().idxmax()
offset -= offset.loc[known]

df.date = df.date.loc[known] + pd.to_timedelta(offset, unit='d')
```

---

#### Details

1. Compute the offsets based on whenever `time` is greater than the subsequent `time`:

```py
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date, dayfirst=True)
df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time, format='%H%M').dt.time
offset = df.time.shift().bfill().gt(df.time).cumsum()

# array([0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3])
```

2. Find a `known` date to use as a pivot point for the offsets (here I used the first non-null date) where the `known` date's offset is 0 and the other offsets are relative to `known`:

```py
known = df.date.notnull().idxmax()
offset -= offset.loc[known]

# array([-2, -1, -1, -1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1])
```

3. Convert the offsets [**`to_timedelta()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and add them to the `known` date:

```py
df.date = df.date.loc[known] + pd.to_timedelta(offset, unit='d')

#          date      time  value
# 0  2020-03-10  11:03:00      5
# 1  2020-03-11  00:10:00     10
# 2  2020-03-11  01:00:00      6
# 3  2020-03-11  02:01:00      8
# 4  2020-03-12  00:15:00      7
# 5  2020-03-12  04:00:00      4
# 6  2020-03-12  05:00:00      6
# 7  2020-03-12  08:00:00      3
# 8  2020-03-12  10:00:00      4
# 9  2020-03-12  11:40:00      5
# 10 2020-03-12  12:00:00      2
# 11 2020-03-13  00:30:00      1
# 12 2020-03-13  01:12:00      0
```

Comment: Good answer! We can simplify `offset.apply(lambda x: df.date.iloc[known] + pd.DateOffset(days=x))` to  `df.date.loc[known] + pd.to_timedelta(offset, unit='d')`  as there is no timezone information present in the date so i guess timedelta would work fine too :)

Comment: @ShubhamSharma ah that makes sense! thanks -- updated

Answer (score 1):

give this a try. I am not familiar with your date format and assume they are in text format

```
currDate=[]

def ffill(row,direction=1):
    global currDate
    if not currDate and pd.isna(row['date']): #could be check if date is blank string
        return None
    if not currDate:
        dt=[int(x) for x in reversed(row['date'].split('.'))]
        dt= datetime.datetime(*dt)
        currDate=[dt, row['time']]
        return dt
    if row['time']*direction>currDate[1]*direction:
        currDate[1]=row['time']
        return currDate[0]
    else:
        currDate=[currDate[0]+relativedelta(days=direction),row['time']]
        return currDate[0]
def bfill(row):
    return ffill(row,-1)
df['ffill']=df.apply(ffill,axis=1)
df.sort_index(0,None,False,True)
currDate=[]
df['bfill']=df.apply(bfill,axis=1)
df.sort_index(0,None,True,True)
df
```